# Local machine SQL dB works; Access Denied Error on Web dB

Tags: php, android, sql, database

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I've managed to utilize the tut to access and properly create accounts/login on my AVM when connecting to a local sql database with EasyPHP. It took a bit of work, but I got it.

I should not that if I use a target SDK of 13+ I get Network on Main Activity Thread error, so for now my target SDK is 3, just so I can learn (so I'm not dealing with the thread issue for now - it's over my head...) So now I'm trying to get the same code to work for my web database hosted on my web domain. Here's my error at the moment:

> 03-29 18:01:26.075: E/JSON(708): Access Denied
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.075: E/JSON Parser(708): Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value Access of type java.lang.String cannot
>   be converted to JSONObject
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.075: D/AndroidRuntime(708): Shutting down VM
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.075: W/dalvikvm(708): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.095: E/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.095: E/AndroidRuntime(708):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.095: E/AndroidRuntime(708):    at
>   com.davekelley.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:59)
>
> 03-29 18:01:26.095: E/AndroidRuntime(708):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) **... plenty more after
>   this**

So I can only assume that this is a SQL db user account issue. Here's the code in my config.php:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "frehud_admin");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "theCorrectPassword");
define("DB_DATABASE", "frehud_android_api");
?>
```

And here's if screenshot of the phpMyAdmin for the dB:[image]
So as you can see, the address would be localhost -> frehud_android_api. And here's a screenshot of the user accounts in MySQL manager: [image]

And here's the URLs that I use in my Java code:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
```

Does anyone have advice as to what could be going wrong here?

EDIT~ Someone requested code:

Login Activity:

```
package com.davekelley;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import library.DatabaseHandler;
import library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

User Functions:

```
package library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class UserFunctions extends AsyncTask {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
    private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
 //http://10.0.2.2/android_api/
    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

JSON Parser:

```
package library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
package library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Screenshot of the file permissions for /android_api:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any sort of java code it is really hard to figure out what is happening, but
looking at the log you've got two lines in the log that make me wonder if it isn't another problem.

```
03-29 18:01:26.075: E/JSON Parser(708): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Access of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Somewhere it is trying to go from String to jsonObject and it is failing.
Can you find out what is being sent in here?  Maybe it isn't a json string.

```
03-29 18:01:26.095: E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You've got a null pointer.  Something is null when the system says it shouldn't be.

I would 1 - See what you are getting that is throwing the JSONException and 2 - See if that null pointer is doing something.

Comment: See that's where I'm having trouble understanding: the code works perfectly with a database that is identical save the user account on my local machine. It's only when I try to get this running with my web dB that I run into trouble. I'd be glad to provide code, I'll paste in some edits up above (at the bottom of the post).

Comment: Well that would indicate to me that something is different from your local setup and the remote setup.  Is the remote server locked so you can't access mysql remotely?

Comment: Well, I did run a test: http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/city.php Which is this code: "<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","frehud_admin","theCorrectPass");
mysql_select_db("frehud_android_api");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from USERS where UID like '1%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>" But I think that error could be because table USERS has no rows yet - the android app would add rows if successful. Also, when I goto /android_api I get Access Denied, but /android_api/include does provide a file listing.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the FTP permissions of the /android_api directory to the bottom of the OP.

Comment: Okay I did click that link and it has a warning.  That 'warning' will throw the JSON Parser and kill it.  I would suggest you put some debug code in and see exactly what you are trying to send to the JSON parser.

Comment: Alright, I added in a catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace();}. I actually get all the same errors that I have showing in my original post but without the app crashing. The first two errors that we've talked about in your original post are still red, but everything that proceeds is now orange. It's having trouble here: 

// check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

Comment: Would assume then that KEY_SUCCESS isn't in the json object then if it is failing their.

Answer (score 0):

Change these

```
private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api";
```

To

```
private static String loginURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/index.php";
private static String registerURL = "http://davidjkelley.net/android_api/index.php";
```

then it will work